# Delete a column in table (PhpMyAdmin/HeidiSQL)

Tags: mysql, heidisql

I would like to know how to delete a column in a table, without deleting the rest of the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ALTER TABLE NameofTable DROP COLUMN ColumnName;

Answer (score 1):

If this column has foreign key you have to go in "Structure" tab, click on "see relational view" below the fields. Here you can remove the foreign keys by selecting an empty value in the dropdown.
After that you should drop column using following comment :
ALTER TABLE 'tableName' DROP COLUMN 'columnName';